# SwiftUI .sheet gets reinitialised when keyboard is opened /closed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image: The return button that is the problem?]

I have this .sheet which I marked in the image, which opens a new view.

The AddRoutineView(...) code is this:

```
struct AddRoutineView: View {
    // Here is the viewModel that is making problems
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : AddRoutineViewModel 
    
    @State private var isCustomShedule = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("ListBackgroundColor")
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Form {
                    Section{
                        TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.name)
                        TextField("Notes", text: $viewModel.note)
                    }
                    Section{
                        DatePicker("Routine start time", selection: $viewModel.startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                        Toggle("Custom Schedule", isOn: $isCustomShedule)
                            .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color(red: 0.808, green: 0.773, blue: 0.987)))
                        
                        if isCustomShedule{
                            withAnimation{
                                WeekdayPicker(selectedWeekday: $viewModel.inetrvalDays)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Section {
                        Button{
                            viewModel.saveRoutine()
                            viewModel.isAddRoutineShowing.wrappedValue = false
                        } label: {
                            ZStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("Confirm")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                           
                            
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                        .disabled(viewModel.isValidForm())

                        Button{
                            viewModel.isAddRoutineShowing.wrappedValue = false
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("cancel")
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color( UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                    }
                }                     
}
            }
            .navigationTitle("new routine.")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I pass the viewModel as an ObservedObject.

Now every time **I hit the return key on my keyboard**, or when I **tip into the text field**, the view is being reinitialised, deleting all content from my viewModel.

```
final class AddRoutineViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var note = ""
    @Published var interval = "Daily"
    @Published var startTime = Date.now
    @Published var inetrvalDays = [
        "Monday" : true,
        "Tuesday": true,
        "Wednesday": true,
        "Thursday": true,
        "Friday": true,
        "Saturday": true,
        "Sunday": true,
    ]
    
    var isAddRoutineShowing: Binding<Bool>
    
    init (isAddRoutineShowing: Binding<Bool>) {
        print("Initialising Add Routine Sheet...")
        self.isAddRoutineShowing = isAddRoutineShowing
    }
    
    func saveRoutine() {
        let newRoutine = Routine(context: PersistenceController.shared.viewContext)
        newRoutine.routineID = UUID()
        newRoutine.active = true
        newRoutine.name = name
        newRoutine.note = note
        newRoutine.interval = encodeWeekdays()
        newRoutine.startTime = startTime
        
        PersistenceController.shared.save()
    }
    
    func isValidForm() -> Bool
    /*
     Gives back true if the form is valid
     */
    {
        var hasWeekdays : Bool = false
        for (_, isActive) in self.inetrvalDays{ if isActive{hasWeekdays = true}}
        return !name.isEmpty && hasWeekdays
    }
}
```

This is my viewModel. I placed the print in the initialiser and it gets reinitialised every time the keyboard opens or closes. I really don't know why.. :D
Is this something about Swifts internal View Update Stuff?

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: With an emphasis on minimal.

Comment: Nor really, that is the problem. If I single out the code that is responsible for the mechanics it works as how I would expect it working... That's why I asked this here to know if in theory it should work how I intended. I guess it's something different in my code that updated that view somehow. Especially because it worked when I first implemented it.

Comment: I figured out the source of the problem. It had nothing to do with the actual implementation / code  for the feature. I wrapped the View in a custom ViewRouter (TabBar) and something there is causing the issue.

Comment: @RudolfKalman Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing a very similar issue, with the entire sheet resetting on focus of a single textfield.

Comment: @LilaQ For me it helped using the .sheet(item: Binding<Identifiable?>) method, instead of the .sheet(isPresented: ...) method. Also, because I saved the boolean that opened the sheet in the Observable Object,and then passed that on to the sheet, every time I changed something in that Observable Object, the view got re-drawn.

Comment: @RudolfKalman Thanks, I will give that a shot. Sadly I can't reliably reproduce the sheet being cleared, so it's a lot of shots in the dark for me. I'll make sure to give feedback when I tried it though.